# Google app engine keeps displaying "Hello world"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, proxy

So a few days ago I made a proxy website app according to a tutorial on http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-proxy-server/12890/. I downloaded and extracted the file. I downloaded python and googleappenginelauncher. I set all of those up and deployed my app to correct ID and so on. Now every time I try to access my app which is based on an index.html file, all the browser displays is "Hello World". The file works perfectly when I try to open it locally, I even tried deploying the index.html only which still resulted in a blank page with Hello World displayed. 
I have discovered that each time I deploy the app, the googleappenginelauncher creates a folder within the root app folder on my computer that contains a main.py file that causes the website to display Hello World. How do I get the deployer app to deploy my app instead of creating Hello World python files?

Comment: You could try the [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (that comes in a trial edition) and add your gae project there for convenience. Then you can work on it with a good organization of your files. I just downloaded your project myself to see how it will work with PyCharm

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please let me know if it works through PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

According to me its better if you can use the Google Cloud SDK to deploy and manage your application.It is the most better approach to upload application locally as well as on production server.Refer to the documents to upload on production server[1], and for local use **dev_appserver.py Application-directory/**

**[1] Upload Application:**  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Uploading_the_app

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create a new project id and use it in your app.yaml file.

I was using an old throwaway project id which had hello world uploaded to it and I got a "  --noauth_local_webserver" in the logs when I was deploying, so it wasn't successful and didn't overwrite the original hello world.

Maybe this was just specifically my case, but thought i'd share.